# How to apply RegEx to whole string?

Tags: android, regex

Is regular expression matching every single string?

For example:

```
String s = "android4you2 and 4us";
```

What's the RegEx that I have to write to make "s" only for [a-z]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear, to match the whole string, you could do:

```
if (s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")) { ...
```

If you want to only test for alphabetic characters:

```
if (s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) { ...
```

Comment: i try like s.getText().matches("[a-zA-Z]$") , but it's only check in the begining of string. how to do it in entire string?

Answer (score 0):

try using this.

```
String regex = "^[A-Za-z\\s]+$";
```